# Register a DB Context with Simple Injector and .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, simple-injector

Hi I'm using Simple Injector for my application DI. I have kept the default DI for framework DI.

But I need to register the `DbContext` with SimpleInjector. When I run the application

```
container.Verify()
```

Gives the following error

> ActivationException: The constructor of type UsersDbContext contains the parameter with name 'options' and type DbContextOptions that is not registered. Please ensure DbContextOptions is registered, or change the constructor of UsersDbContext.

I'm registering the DbContext with SimpleInjectore in a function `SimpleInjectorConfig.InitializeContainer(app, _container)`

```
// DbContext
container.Register<DbContext, UsersDbContext>();
```

And my Startup is

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var conString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conString));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    IdentityConfigurationService.ConfigureIdentityOptions(services);

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services
    services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(_container));
    services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(_container));

    services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(_container);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    SimpleInjectorConfig.InitializeContainer(app, _container);

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    _container.Verify();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I know the problem is with the options, but I don't know how Simple Injector needs the default Connection string registered to the container. Is this something that can be passed to Simple Injector ? or should I use the `DbContextFactory` to pass the connection string to `UserDbContext` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell SimpleInjector how to instantiate the `UsersDbContext` which seems to have a constructor with the parameter of type `DbContextOptions`.

Change how you register your `DbContext` by using an overload of `Register` method that take a delegate (factory) parameter like below:

```
container.Register<DbContext>(() => {
    var options = // Configure your DbContextOptions here
    return new UsersDbContext(options);
});
```

Comment: this answer worked and is the answer to what I asked but in the end I ended up cross-wiring the DbContext since I had already added it to the the default DI Container in StartUp.cs

Comment: @JeffFinn can you show a snippet of what your 'cross-wiring' solution looks like?

Answer (score 1):

All answers don't work for me, but I found another approach.

```
container.CrossWire<IntellisenseDbContext>(app);
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor and pass options object as dependency. Register options in DI as well. You can setup connection string in `OnConfiguring` method:

```
public partial class FooContext : DbContext
{
    private FooContextOptions _options;

    public FooContext(FooContextOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_options.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to what I asked but it is an alternative that I ended up using. Maybe this might be useful to others in the future

I cross-wired the DbContext from the default DI Container.

```
container.Register(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<UsersDbContext>, Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

After looking at my DI configuration I felt this was a better solution because my DbContext is only registered in one place. I was happy to leave it there because I am using Entity Framework and Identity. Both of these are registered to the default DI container that I'm keeping for registering Framework dependencies and they need access to the DbContext

Comment: For this to work properly, please take a look at https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/398#issuecomment-291058077

Comment: Not sure you can safely register a DbContext as a singleton, the number of held objects will increase overtime and DbContext should be created per-request